# How to set a timer around an Image rendering event

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm working on a Google appengine Java project. I need to render an image from an external source and insert it in to a pdf.

```
    Image im = null;
    if(!home.getImageLocation().isEmpty()){
        im = Report.getImage(pdf, new Link(home.getImageLocation()));

    }else{
        System.out.println("Image location not found!");
    }
```

Sometimes I get the pdf without the image. I need to set a timer around the image rendering statement and give an error message at timeout.
What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I like this question!  The answer is to use Threads within the constraints imposed by [The sandbox](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox).  Start two worker threads, one for the image processing and the other for a fixed interval timer.  The main thread should monitor both worker threads and detect which one ends first.  The main thread should then clean up both worker threads and generate a success or failure response.

If the image processing code can regulate its own amount of processing, say by varying an image resolution (probably not in your scenario), the image processing thread can adjust its own amount of work to do after querying ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis() as documented in [The request timer](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_request_timer).